# Get checkbox value using onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using multiple check-boxes for some action. My requirement is to get `on` if the checkbox is checked and `off` when it is unchecked. But I am getting the value as `on` if I check/uncheck the checkbox.

```
<label class="cont">
   <input type="checkbox" name="listingstatus" id="listingstatus<?php echo $doc->module_video_id; ?>" onchange="listingStatus('<?php echo $doc->module_video_id; ?>')">
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>


function listingStatus(module_video_id)
{
  var a = $('#listingstatus'+module_video_id).val();
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `is(":checked")` with ternary operator:

```
var a = $('#listingstatus'+module_video_id).is(":checked") ? 'on' : 'off';
```

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using plain vanilla Javascript you'd go with something like this:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const checkedInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'));
  const values = [];
  checkedInputs.forEach((checkbox) => {
    values.push(checkbox.value);
  })
  console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" value="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" value="baz" />
<input type="checkbox" value="wtf" />
<button type="button" id="btn">Console.log checked values</button>
```

If you need something different, please try to be more clear in what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use .checked instead of .value:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" onchange="foo()">

<script>
function listingStatus()
{
  var isChecked = document.getElementById('chkBox').checked;
  console.log(isChecked);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if checkbox is checked or not by using below script

```
function listingStatus(module_video_id)
    {
        if ($('#listingstatus' + module_video_id).prop('checked')) {
            console.log('checked do stuff here');
        } else {
            console.log('not checked');
        }
    }
```